# different Livevalidation depending from States at the Javascript don´t work

Tags: javascript, livevalidation

I use the Livevalidation successful in Standard-Forms. When i use the Valdidation in modified Forms by JavaScript it won’t work reliable.

### It should work like these instructions:

```
<Input type="Ratio" value="1">: Validation for "Submit" not necessary
<Input type="Ratio" value="-1">: Validation necessary
<Input type="Ratio" value="-2">: Validation necessary
```

### The first Problem:

- when i select "value -1" Livevalidation don´t work
- when i select "value -2" Livevalidation works
- when i select "value -1" (after -2) Livevalidation works

### The second Problem:

- when i select "value 1" i can "Submit" the form
- but....
- when i select "value -1" or "value -2" and Livevalidation is active
- then i select "value 1" (Livevalidation not necessary) i can not "submit" the form

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function changeState(state) {

     var id = parseInt(state);

     if (id >= 0)
     {
          $('#new_delivery_address').hide("slow");
          $('#packstation').remove();

          // Livevalidation
          var title = new LiveValidation('title');
          var firstName = new LiveValidation('firstName');
          var lastName = new LiveValidation('lastName');
          var firm = new LiveValidation('firm');
          var street = new LiveValidation('street');
          var streetnumber = new LiveValidation('streetnumber');  
          var street2 = new LiveValidation('street2');        
          var plz = new LiveValidation('plz');    
          var city = new LiveValidation('city');  
          var tel = new LiveValidation('tel');

          title.destroy(true);
          firstName.destroy(true);
          lastName.destroy(true);
          firm.destroy(true);
          street.destroy(true);
          streetnumber.destroy(true);
          street2.destroy(true);
          plz.destroy(true);
          city.destroy(true);
          tel.destroy(true);
      }
     if (id == -2) 
     {

          // Code
          // Code
          // ...

          // Livevalidierung
          var title = new LiveValidation('title');
          var firstName = new LiveValidation('firstName');
          var lastName = new LiveValidation('lastName');
          var firm = new LiveValidation('firm');
          var street = new LiveValidation('street');
          var street2 = new LiveValidation('street2');        
          var plz = new LiveValidation('plz');    
          var city = new LiveValidation('city');  
          var tel = new LiveValidation('tel');    

          firstName.add( Validate.Presence);
          lastName.add( Validate.Presence);
          street.add(Validate.Presence);
          street2.add(Validate.Presence);
          plz.add(Validate.Presence);             
          plz.add(Validate.Numericality);
          plz.add(Validate.Length, { minimum: 4, maximum: 5 } );
          city.add(Validate.Presence);
          streetnumber.destroy(true);
     }
     if (id == -1)
     {

          // Code
          // Code
          // ...

          // Livevalidierung
          var title = new LiveValidation('title');
          var firstName = new LiveValidation('firstName');
          var lastName = new LiveValidation('lastName');
          var firm = new LiveValidation('firm');
          var street = new LiveValidation('street');
          var streetnumber = new LiveValidation('streetnumber');      
          var street2 = new LiveValidation('street2');        
          var plz = new LiveValidation('plz');    
          var city = new LiveValidation('city');  
          var tel = new LiveValidation('tel');    

          firstName.add( Validate.Presence);
          lastName.add( Validate.Presence);
          street.add(Validate.Presence);
          streetnumber.add(Validate.Presence);
          plz.add(Validate.Presence);             
          plz.add(Validate.Numericality);
          plz.add(Validate.Length, { minimum: 4, maximum: 5 } );
          city.add(Validate.Presence);
          street2.destroy(true);
     }
  }

  function 123 () {
      // Code
      // Code
      // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: could no one help me?

Comment: I have found an answer on a thread with a similar problem - but I don´t know to interpret it for my code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6286561

Answer (score 0):

Now i had found a solution for "The second Problem:....can not "submit" the form"

I worked in Addition with the arguments **disable(function)** and **enable(function)**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function changeState(state) {

   var id = parseInt(state);

   if (id >= 0)
   {
        $('#new_delivery_address').hide("slow");
        $('#packstation').remove();

        // Livevalidation
        var title = new LiveValidation('title');
        var firstName = new LiveValidation('firstName');
        var lastName = new LiveValidation('lastName');
        var firm = new LiveValidation('firm');
        var street = new LiveValidation('street');
        var streetnumber = new LiveValidation('streetnumber');      
        var street2 = new LiveValidation('street2');        
        var plz = new LiveValidation('plz');    
        var city = new LiveValidation('city');  
        var tel = new LiveValidation('tel');    

        title.destroy(true);
        firstName.destroy(true);
        lastName.destroy(true);
        firm.destroy(true);
        street.destroy(true);
        streetnumber.destroy(true);
        street2.destroy(true);
        plz.destroy(true);
        city.destroy(true);
        tel.destroy(true);

        title.disable(true);
        firstName.disable(true);
        lastName.disable(true);
        firm.disable(true);
        street.disable(true);
        streetnumber.disable(true);
        street2.disable(true);
        plz.disable(true);
        city.disable(true);
        tel.disable(true);
    }
   if (id == -2) 
   {

        // Code
        // Code
        // ...

        // Livevalidierung
        var title = new LiveValidation('title');
        var firstName = new LiveValidation('firstName');
        var lastName = new LiveValidation('lastName');
        var firm = new LiveValidation('firm');
        var street = new LiveValidation('street');
        var street2 = new LiveValidation('street2');        
        var plz = new LiveValidation('plz');    
        var city = new LiveValidation('city');  
        var tel = new LiveValidation('tel');    

        title.enable(true);
        firstName.enable(true);
        lastName.enable(true);
        firm.enable(true);
        street.enable(true);
        street2.enable(true);
        plz.enable(true);
        city.enable(true);
        tel.enable(true);

        lastName.add(Validate.Presence);
        street.add(Validate.Presence);
        street2.add(Validate.Presence);
        plz.add(Validate.Presence);             
        plz.add(Validate.Numericality);
        plz.add(Validate.Length, { minimum: 4, maximum: 5 } );
        city.add(Validate.Presence);
        streetnumber.destroy(true);
        streetnumber.remove(true);  
   }
   if (id == -1)
   {

        // Code
        // Code
        // ...

        // Livevalidierung
        var title = new LiveValidation('title');
        var firstName = new LiveValidation('firstName');
        var lastName = new LiveValidation('lastName');
        var firm = new LiveValidation('firm');
        var street = new LiveValidation('street');
        var streetnumber = new LiveValidation('streetnumber');      
        var street2 = new LiveValidation('street2');        
        var plz = new LiveValidation('plz');    
        var city = new LiveValidation('city');  
        var tel = new LiveValidation('tel');    

        title.enable(true);
        firstName.enable(true);
        lastName.enable(true);
        firm.enable(true);
        street.enable(true);
        streetnumber.enable(true);
        street2.enable(true);
        plz.enable(true);
        city.enable(true);
        tel.enable(true);

        lastName.add(Validate.Presence);
        street.add(Validate.Presence);
        streetnumber.add(Validate.Presence);
        plz.add(Validate.Presence);             
        plz.add(Validate.Numericality);
        plz.add(Validate.Length, { minimum: 4, maximum: 5 } );
        city.add(Validate.Presence);
        street2.destroy(true);
        street2.remove(true);   
   }
}

function 123 () {
    // Code
    // Code
    // ...
}
```

### But the "First Problem" is still existing:

- when i select "value -1" Livevalidation don´t work
- when i select "value -2" Livevalidation works
- when i select "value -1" (after -2) Livevalidation works also

### and now additional with the disable/enable-function also:

- when i select "value -1" input-fields are enabled
- then i select "value 1" input-fields are disbled
- when i select "value -1" again input-fields are still disbled!!
- only when i select "value -2"
- then select "value -1" again input-fields works